# Error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64' <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes> (don't know what to do)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to plot an equation that contains and definite integral. It is a photoionisation cross section associated with the intersubband transitions in a two-dimensional quantum ring. I made the angular part analytically, and I'm trying to calculate numerically the radial part.

Here's my attempt to implement this in a Python code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma
from scipy.constants import alpha
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Constants
epsilon = 13.1 #dielectric constant of the material
gamma_C = 0.5 # donor impurity linewidth 
nr = 3.2 #refractive index of semiconductor
flux = 0  # Phi in eqn 8 magnetic flux
R = 5  #radius of the qunatum ring in nm
r = np.linspace(0, 6 * R)
rho = r / R
m_0 = 0.0067*0.511 # electron effective mass
h = 4.13e-15 # Planck constant in eV
hbar =  6.58e-16 # reduced Planck constant in eV
#Photon energy
hnu = np.linspace(0, 100) #in eV


#Function that calculates the integrand
def func(rho):
    betai = np.sqrt( gama**4/4)
    betaf = np.sqrt(1+gama**4/2)
    return ((gama * rho)**(betai + betaf) *
            np.exp(-1/2*(gama * rho)**2) 
         * (gama * rho)**2/2   ) 

def cross_section(hnu, gama):
    #function that calculates the photoionisation cross section
    betai = np.sqrt( gama**4/4)
    betaf = np.sqrt(1+gama**4/2)
    Ei = gama**2*(1+betai)-gama**4/2
    Ef = gama**2*(3+betaf)-gama**4/2
    return (nr/epsilon * 4*np.pi/3 * alpha * hnu *
            (abs(R * np.sqrt(1/2**betai*gamma(betai + 1))*
            np.sqrt(1/2**betaf*gamma(betaf + 1)) *
            quad(func, 0, np.infty))**2 * 
             hbar * gamma_C/(Ef - Ei - hnu)**2 + ( hbar * gamma_C)**2))

#Plot

plt.figure();plt.clf()

for gama in [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]:
    plt.plot(hnu, cross_section(hnu, gama))
```

But I keep receiving this error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'
```

Anyone knows the cause and how can avoid this?

Comment: Follow the stack trace, run a debugger, and if you are still stuck, make an MCVE.

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there that could help someone (including you) find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another look at the docstring for [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html).  In particular, look at the 'Returns' section.  You'll see that it returns multiple values.  More precisely, it returns a tuple of values.  The actual number of values depends on the parameter `full_output`, but it always includes at least two values, the numerically computed integral and the error estimate.

In this code

```
    return (nr/epsilon * 4*np.pi/3 * alpha * hnu *
            (abs(R * np.sqrt(1/2**betai*gamma(betai + 1))*
            np.sqrt(1/2**betaf*gamma(betaf + 1)) *
            quad(func, 0, np.infty))**2 * 
             hbar * gamma_C/(Ef - Ei - hnu)**2 + ( hbar * gamma_C)**2))
```

you use the return value of `quad`, but that is a tuple, so it won't work correctly in that expression.   To fix it, just pull out the first value of the tuple returned by `quad`.  That is, replace `quad(func, 0, np.infty)` with `quad(func, 0, np.infty)[0]`:

```
    return (nr/epsilon * 4*np.pi/3 * alpha * hnu *
            (abs(R * np.sqrt(1/2**betai*gamma(betai + 1))*
            np.sqrt(1/2**betaf*gamma(betaf + 1)) *
            quad(func, 0, np.infty)[0])**2 * 
             hbar * gamma_C/(Ef - Ei - hnu)**2 + ( hbar * gamma_C)**2))
```

Comment: The order of the values is as documented in the docstring.  The first one is the numerically computed integral, and the second is the estimate of the error.